# jqGrid is not rendering mvc3 razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

My _Layout.cshtml like this

```
 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - E-Reader Statistics</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
       @* @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")*@
        <link href="~/jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/jqGrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
        <script src="~/jqGrid/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>


    </head>
```

in Index.chtml

```
@model List<LSStatisticalReport.ViewModels.GSViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@*<h2>General Statistics</h2>*@

<script type="text/javascript">
   // var jq = $.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var genStatGrid = $('#list');

        genStatGrid.jqGrid({
            caption: "General Statistics",
            url: '/Statistics/GetRecords/',
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['Student', 'Teacher', 'Date'],
            colModel: [
                            { name: 'studentDesignation' },
                            { name: 'teacherDesignation' },
                            { name: 'dateLength' },
              ],
            rowNum: 5
        });
    });
</script>
```

But when I am running the project I am getting an error in console:

**"Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jqGrid' "**

Comment: `jquery-1.9.0.min.js` should be written before `grid.locale-en.js`

Answer (score 0):

This type of error says this : please Define jqgrid library before related init scripts. I have seen this error before, although you have defined related library in head tag. So I solved this problem by removing its library from head tag and placing it at the view before the script and works properly.

I think this occurs because of partial load of page. so use this at the index view:

```
@model List<LSStatisticalReport.ViewModels.GSViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@*<h2>General Statistics</h2>*@
//added
<script src="~/jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>
//end added
<script type="text/javascript">
   // var jq = $.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var genStatGrid = $('#list');

        genStatGrid.jqGrid({
            caption: "General Statistics",
            url: '/Statistics/GetRecords/',
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['Student', 'Teacher', 'Date'],
            colModel: [
                            { name: 'studentDesignation' },
                            { name: 'teacherDesignation' },
                            { name: 'dateLength' },
              ],
            rowNum: 5
        });
    });
</script>
```